# In Robot Framework test case documentation, is there a way to have an indented sub list within a list item?

Tags: html, robotframework

Sorry if the wording is a bit off.

I am wanting to make a list similar to the one displayed below.

- This is a list item

  - This is a sub
- This is a list item

Currently, I am able to make a list in Robot Framework documentation like this...

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test Case 1
    [Documentation]         = Title =
    ...                     ---
    ...                     == Steps ==
    ...                     - Step 1
    ...                     - Step 2
    ...                     - Step 3

    No Operation
```

And it will then show up in the report like the following picture.

[image: Report.html]

Is there any way for me to create an indented "sub-list" without post processing the html/css?

Comment: According to the user guide, no there is not.

Comment: Thanks, @BryanOakley. I concluded the same, just didn't know if there might be a rebot command or something to do this.